# Circular Reference with drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible in MS. Excel or VBA to have a circular reference with a drop-down list?

Here is what I am after: I want to generate on two sheets (sheet 1, sheet 2) a drop down list that says either "Complete" or "Incomplete."  If I change sheet 1 from Complete to Incomplete, I want sheet 2 to say the same thing, but I also want vice versa
(If I change sheet 2 from Complete to Incomplete, I want sheet 1 to change).

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: if you are using dropdown form control, just assign same linked cell for both the dropdowns

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  Here is my question on SU:http://superuser.com/questions/1031660/linked-dropdown-lists

Comment: "circular references" is not exactly translatable from Excel formulas to VBA. In VBA, you can [for example] make x = y, then make y = x + 1, then make x = y + x. This works because each line is done in order, so it doesn't run back and forth recomputing. You can't do this with Excel formulas because all cells update at the same time; there is no 'order of operations' between cells. So you cant make A1 = B1, and then make B1 = A1 + 1, because it would keep looping forever. So what this question is basically asking is, is: can a sub impact a cell differently depending on that cell's value? Yes.

Answer (score 5):

Acting on a change in any of the worksheets' B5 range seems a likely way to proceed but the individual [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macros have some limitations.

The code has to be repeated across many worksheet code sheets and any modifications have to be cloned across the same. New worksheets require the sub procedure to be incorporated into their own code sheets.

Without disabling events before writing new values, each worksheet receiving a new value is going to initiate its own [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro which in turn will rewrite values which will trigger more events. A cascade event failure is almost sure to happen.

By exchanging the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro for the more universal [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro located in the **ThisWorkbook** code sheet, all of the code can be localized to a single location. Adjustments are made in a single place and new worksheet will automatically be added to the queue of worksheets to process. They can easily be added to the array of worksheet **not** to process as well.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" And Sh.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim w As Long
        For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w)
                'skip this worksheet and Sheet3
                If CBool(UBound(Filter(Array(Sh.Name, "Sheet3"), _
                        .Name, False, vbTextCompare))) Then
                    .Range("B5") = Target.Value
                    '.Range("B5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  '<~~testing purposes
                End If
            End With
        Next w
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any worksheet that is not to receive an update to the value in its own B5 cell can be added to the array used in the [Filter function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s.aspx). Currently, Sheet3 and the worksheet that initiated the Workbook_SheetChange event are excluded.

Comment: This is more elegant and efficient. I caught the cascade event failure though by checking if the value is the same, if it is the same no  change is made thus no new event.

Comment: I didn't mean the oblique reference disparagingly; merely to clarify a potential problem area from a wide viewpoint. Hope it wasn't taken in the wrong manner.

Comment: Not at all. It was one of the problems I encountered truth be told.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a hidden sheet that contains the range for input and the linked cell.  Then link both drop downs to the list and the linked cell.  Then when you change one it will change the other.  The key here is the Linked Cell.  This is assuming Excel 2013, using the Form control Combo Box.

Comment: This is what I've been working towards but using a form control makes it tough if you're going to have dozens of these linked dropdowns.  Ideas there?

Comment: if all the combo boxes are going to reference the same linked cell then a simple UDF to automate the linking would work.  Would need more information on the combo boxes and how they are tied together

Comment: In my scenario they would all be different values.  There could be hundreds.  Currently I just use validation lists and have 1-way links, so I have to tell people not to change the value on the dashboard tab.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [@Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810800/circular-reference-with-drop-down-list/35027989#35027989) as it is the most efficient answer.

---

After a little trial and error I've gotten this to work with a cell with a "Data Validation" dropdown menu. In my test case, I had 3 sheets with a Data Validation list in cell $B$5 on each worksheet linked to a list on a hidden sheet to populate the list, the sheet with the options list was "Sheet3" and did not contain a data validation list.

The Code below needs to be copied to every sheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Not ws.Name = Me.Name And Not ws.Name = "Sheet3" Then
                If Not ws.Range(Target.Address) = Me.Range(Target.Address) Then
                    ws.Range(Target.Address) = Me.Range(Target.Address)
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This is fairly easy with activeX comboboxes on the sheets

On the workbook module add the code below to populate the comboboxes

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
            .AddItem "Complete"
            .AddItem "Incomplete"
        End With
        With .Worksheets("Sheet2").ComboBox1
            .AddItem "Complete"
            .AddItem "Incomplete"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

On the "Sheet1" Module add

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1 = "Complete" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ComboBox1.Value = "Complete"
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1 = "Incomplete" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ComboBox1.Value = "Incomplete"
    End If
End Sub
```

On the "Sheet2" Module add

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1 = "Complete" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value = "Complete"
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1 = "Incomplete" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value = "Incomplete"
    End If
End Sub
```