# Dropdown list circular reference Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am following up on an answer that has been posted before at the following link: [Circular Reference with drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810800/circular-reference-with-drop-down-list/75485407#75485407)

The answer works when the dropdown lists and sources are on the same cell on their respective sheets, but I am trying to find out how this work if the lists and source are not on the same cell. Thank you

I am following this answer:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" And Sh.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim w As Long
        For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w)
                'skip this worksheet and Sheet3
                If CBool(UBound(Filter(Array(Sh.Name, "Sheet3"), _
                        .Name, False, vbTextCompare))) Then
                    .Range("B5") = Target.Value
                    '.Range("B5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  '<~~testing purposes
                End If
            End With
        Next w
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to have two lists where I can change one and it'll update the other. How do I create the same result in the dropdown for example on cell A3 on Sheet1 and D9 on Sheet2?

Here is what I am after: I want to generate on two sheets (sheet 1, sheet 2) a drop-down list that says either "Complete" or "Incomplete." If I change sheet 1 from Complete to Incomplete, I want sheet 2 to say the same thing, but I also want vice versa
(If I change sheet 2 from Complete to Incomplete, I want sheet 1 to change).

Comment: Better to post the code you're using here - you can still reference the other post, but you haven't told us *which* answer you're trying to follow...

Comment: You will need some way for your code to know where the list cell is on each sheet.   You can either put that in your code, or on a hidden worksheet, depending on how many cells you need to map.  Is there only on list per sheet?   You could also give each cell with the same list the same (worksheet-scoped) name, so you can easily find the list on each sheet.

Comment: I am looking to put it into the code. There is only one list per sheet and I only need to map those two lists. On a third sheet, I have the source for the data validation list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim arrCells, el, i As Long, m, tgt, arr
    
    arrCells = Array("Sheet1|D3", "Sheet2|B4") 'all cells with the list
    
    tgt = Sh.Name & "|" & Target.Address(False, False)
    m = Application.Match(tgt, arrCells, 0) 'matches one of the list cells?
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = LBound(arrCells) To UBound(arrCells)
            If arrCells(i) <> tgt Then 'skip the cell raising the event...
                arr = Split(arrCells(i), "|")
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)).Range(arr(1)).Value = Target.Value
            End If
        Next i
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```